# Update User Details and save it into existing dictionary with user details

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutabledictionary

I have a dicionary on ViewControllerA,I am passing that dictionary to ViewController B through Segue.The detailsDictionary contains user details as follows:

```
{
    City = abc;
    Country = Indi;
    DOB = "12/3/2016 12:00:00 AM";
    EmailID = "abc@gmail.com";
    FName = dhruv;
    LName = kumar;
    MName = Singh;
    Password = "";
    State = Chandigarh;
    UserID = "f2266e5d-c709-42fb-ad98-b75873ac2fd1";
}
```

Now on View Controller B there are texfields with which the user can update their details and post the updated details to server.I have used the following code for it

```
 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        NSInteger field = textField.tag;
        NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"fname"];

        }
        if(field ==2)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"mname"];


        }

        if(field ==3)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"lname"];
        }

        if(field ==4)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"city"];
        }

        if(field ==5)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"state"];
        }

        if(field ==6)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"country"];
        }

        if(field ==7)
        { 
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"dob"];
        }  
    }
```

I want that if user updates their detail then new updated details get saved in detailsDictionary ,else if user doesn't make any change detailsDictionary keeps the previous details.But,I am not able to achieve this.I am not understanding that how can I check the dictionary for new details and change the values in case of new details or keep the old values in case of no change.Kindly help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Get the value for key fname from _detailsDictionary and check wether that is equals to textField.text if NO, then [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"FName"]; else dont do anything.

Comment: can you show ur viewdidload

Comment: I have done nothing in viewdidload

Comment: just show ur viewdidload code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it correctly, just you need to make sure that the key will be same which user is updating as the keys are case sensitive so you need to make sure you will use the same key, as in your code you are using lowercase while the key contains some uppercase letters

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        NSInteger field = textField.tag;
        if(field ==1)
        {

        NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"FName"];

        }
        if(field ==2)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"MName"];


        }

        if(field ==3)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"LName"];
        }

        if(field ==4)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"City"];
        }

        if(field ==5)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"State"];
        }

        if(field ==6)
        {
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"Country"];
        }

        if(field ==7)
        { 
            NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
            [_detailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"DOB"];
        }  
    }
```

Comment: Sir,all the dictionaries I ma using here are NSMutabledictionary but after adding new entry to FName textfield when i move to next textfield it shows error "
2016-11-03 11:02:17.841 FlairRate[1227:27984] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'"......and I am not able to understand the cause for this error.

Comment: the dictionary which you are assigning to your NSMutabledictionary is not mutable, assign it like this `_detailsDictionary = [yourDict mutableCopy]`, then you will not get this error